# angularjs ng-repeat with dynamic json/object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looking a solution for dynamic data structure(inconsistent like different property name and property length) with ng-repeat. sample code are below.

```
    $scope.data = [{
        "table":[{
        "employee":"name1",
        "value1":"10",
        "value2":"20"
        },
        {
        "employee":"name2",
        "value1":"15",
        "value2":"30"
        }]
    },
    {
        "table":[{
        "company":"name1",
        "compnayValue":"12"
        },
        {
        "company":"name2",
        "compnayValue":"12"
        }]
    }]

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in item.table">
                    <td>{{??}}</td>
                    <td>{{??}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in those `{{??}}` for example? what is the desired output based on the shared data?

Comment: either its a {{row.employee}} or {{row.company}}, so my question is how could i handle these dynamic property name?

Comment: so you don't want to display other properties like `value1`, `compnayValue` etc? What is the criteria for picking which property to display?

Comment: Yes, I want display all property, just answered for you only with the example.

Comment: hope the answer helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enumerate all properties and display their values by another `ng-repeat` on `td`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in item.table">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">
        {{row[key]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</li>
```

but that would break the tabular format of data since some rows would have more `td`s. To prevent that you could first find out the set of all keys on all rows, do a `th` repeat with those first and then display them on the corresponding `td` below, e.g.:

```
<th ng-repeat="propertyName in allPossiblePropertyNames">
  {{propertyName}}
</th>
```

and

```
<td ng-repeat="propertyName in allPossiblePropertyNames">
  {{row[propertyName ]}}
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you all, I think this is a simple solution and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<tbody>` to represent an object inside `table` array and `(key,value)` syntax mentioned in [iterating over object properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties) section to iterate over it's properties like:

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "table": [{
      "employee": "name1",
      "value1": "10",
      "value2": "20"
    }, {
      "employee": "name2",
      "value1": "15",
      "value2": "30"
    }]
  }, {
    "table": [{
      "company": "name1",
      "compnayValue": "12"
    }, {
      "company": "name2",
      "compnayValue": "12"
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
tbody:nth-child(odd) tr {
  color: #fff;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
tbody:nth-child(even) tr {
  color: #fff;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
      <table>
        <tbody ng-repeat="row in item.table">
          <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">
            <td>
              {{key}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{value}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this plunker, you can define template depends on your data : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/fVGhKZy5gnBzuPwspy5s?p=preview

Use angular filter :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.data = [{
      "table":[{
      "employee":"name1",
      "value1":"10",
      "value2":"20"
      },
      {
      "employee":"name2",
      "value1":"15",
      "value2":"30"
      }]
  },
  {
      "table":[{
      "company":"name1",
      "compnayValue":"12"
      },
    {
    "company":"name2",
    "compnayValue":"12"
    }]
  }]
 })
  .filter('isCompnay', function() {
   return function(input) {
   console.log(input.employee === undefined)
   return input.company ? input : undefined;
  };
})
.filter('isEmployee', function() {
return function(input) {
  console.log(input.employee === undefined)
  return input.employee ? input : undefined;
   };
 });
```